# Using More than 2 Entity Relationships in Report Builder (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I've created a model using SQL Server Reporting Services. When I try to create a report using the Report Builder, I can drag an entity to the report, followed by a nested sub-entity. I get the two-level grouping as expected.

However, I cannot add a third level entity to the relationship, no matter which combination I try.

What can I do to enable multi level entity relationships in Report Builder?

Comment: Ugh...hearing this makes me yearn for Cognos.  I guess you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had lots of time to play here. I haven't found a way using standard role relationships. Instead, I created a named query that joins multiple tables together. I then create folders in the model for each column, depending on from which table they originate. This mimics, more or less, the effect of having multiple entities.

I find that this, and using the table wizards and flexible tablix groupings in Report Builder 2.0 work pretty well.

Comment: I've received some feedback from Microsoft regarding this. Apparently, using a "flat" query is the way around this. Still, I find myself creating a very large, complex query which is starting to put a heavy load on the server. I'm still open to ideas.